# How to set a bucket's ACL on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, acl

I tried a couple of things: [S3Browse](http://s3browse.com/), the [RightAws Ruby gem](http://rightaws.rubyforge.org/) and other tools.  All allow granting access on an individual key basis, but I wasn't able to set the ACL on buckets.  Actually, I set the ACL on the bucket, no errors are returned. But when I refresh or check in another tool, the bucket's ACL is reset to owner only.

I want to give read and write access to [FlixCloud](http://flixcloud.com/) for an application I'm developing.  They need the access to write the output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, just checked it again after 10 min. ACL remains as configured. I guess this is something at your end then. Try different account/workstation.

Comment: Forgot to ever answer this. My problem was a script I had written which overwrote the ACL a couple of minutes later.

Answer (score 12):

I was struggling with the ACL vs. Bucket Policy and found the following useful.

**ACL**

The ACL defines the permissions attached to a single file in your bucket.  The Bucket Policy is a script that explains the permissions for any folder or file in a bucket.  Use the bucket polcies to restrict hot linking, grant or deny access to specific or all files, restrict IP address, etc.

**Edit the S3 Bucket Policy**

Log into Amazon Web Services, click to S3 and click on the bucket name in the left column.  View the bucket Properties panel at the bottom of the page.  Click the button on the lower right corner that says "Edit bucket policy".  This brings up a lightbox that you can paste the policy script into.  If the script fails validation it will not save.

Sample Policy that enabled read access to everyone (useful if the bucket is being used as a content delivery network)

```
{
     "Version": "2008-10-17",
     "Id": "",
     "Statement": [
          {
               "Sid": "AddPerm",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "*"
               },
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
          }
     ]
}
```

Sample policy to prevent unauthorized hotlinking (third party sites linking to it) but allow anybody to download the files:

```
{ 
    "Version":"2008-10-17", 
    "Id":"preventHotLinking",

    "Statement":[ { 

        "Sid":"1", 
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS":"*"
        },

        "Action":"s3:GetObject",
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::your.bucket.name/*",

        "Condition":{

            "StringLike": { 

                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://yourwebsitename.com/*", 
                    "http://www.yourwebsitename.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

**Generate a Policy**

http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

**Sample Bucket Policies**

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html

Comment: Bucket policies are great, one caveat... They only work for objects owned by the buckets owner. So if your content ends up in your bucket through a user account other than bucket owner, you need to use ACL's or copy paste the object in the bucket as owner to reset the owner.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Steve, I didn't know about the object owner caveat.

Answer (score 1):

I have just double checked that for you - [S3fm](http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html) was able to change the ACL successfully. I used their email **s3@flixcloud.com** as userid. You can see the user in the list afterwords as **flixclouds3**.

Comment: Did you check the ACL after 1 or 2 minutes?  On my end, the ACL is always reset to owner only.