# Make the object publicly readable in Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I am working on Amazon S3 sdk for storing files on cloud server,i am using codeplex's threesharp(http://threesharp.codeplex.com) for implementing this, I have successfully uploaded file on server now i have to download it, and for this i have to download it with the URL eg https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/Filename

I can download the uploaded file but it is appearing blank, if i upload a text file then after downloading it's showing nothing in it,same as images and other files. I have read on Amazon S3 documentation that i'll have to make  the object publically readable(http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/OpeningAnObject.html) i dont have any idea how to achieve this.
How can i accomplish the download functionality? 
Threesharp project is a desktop based and i am working on web based application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During file upload set proper ACL:

Eg.:

```
AmazonS3 client = GetS3Client();
SetACLRequest request = new SetACLRequest();
request.BucketName = "my-new-bucket";
request.Key        = "hello.txt";
request.CannedACL  = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
client.SetACL(request)
```

Amazon S3 provides a rich set of mechanisms for you to manage access to your buckets and objects.

Check this for detail: [Amazon S3 Bucket Public Access Considerations](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5050)

Also, You can Download Explorer for Amazon S3 (Eg. [CloudBerry Explorer for Amazon S3](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx)) & they you can assign appropriate rights to your buckets.

**CloudBerry Explorer for Amazon S3:** Data Access Feature:

- **Bucket Policy Editor**
  Create and edit conditional rules for managing access to the buckets and objects.
- **ACL Editor**
  Manage access permission to any of your objects by setting up 'Access Control List'. ACL will also apply to all 'child objects' inside S3 buckets.

Also, you can do the same using Amazon S3 admin console.

Eg.

Comment: this will make my bucket public? Then will i be able to download the files as well?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

1. Right-click the object and click Make public
2. Select the object and in the Permissions section checked Open/Download ?

**edit:**

have you taken a look here: 
[How to set the permission on files at the time of Upload through Amazon s3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863477/how-to-set-the-permission-on-files-at-the-time-of-upload-through-amazon-s3-api)

and here:

[How to set a bucket's ACL on S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127401/how-to-set-a-buckets-acl-on-s3)

It might guide you in the right direction

Comment: Yes i know this,but what if i have thousand objects it's nonsense  to make 1000 objects publically like that

Comment: i want to make it publically available through request or Signed URL(i dont have idea of both)

Comment: I've looked in first link,my request is making similar as it explained  :(